# Using Eclipse plugin without any extension-point

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

By defining extension-points Eclipse plugins provide a way for third party plugins to add new enhancements to the original plugin. My question is that, if the original plugin has not defined any extension-points and if I add this plugin as dependency to my plugin, can I use it's classes in my plugin's code? I tried this. I couldn't find any extension points in extension tab. However, I could import classes belonging to the original plugin in my code even if the original plugin does not define any extension-points.

For e.g.

import originalplugin.class;

I was hoping to see compile errors as no extension-points have been defined by the original plugin but I can still import some of it's classes in my plugin's code without any complilation error. I want to understand reason behind this. Even if extension-points have not been defined by a plugin what is the reason that one can still use some of it's classes? What are the limitations? What are the side effects? I am a complete novice to eclipse plugin development. My apologies if my queries are too basic or ignorant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extension points to use the classes in another plug-in. But you can only use the classes in the packages that the plug-in has declared in its `Export-Package` list in its `MANIFEST.MF`. This is the normal way to use many classes provided by plug-ins.

Many plug-ins will only export a limited number of their classes, perhaps just the interfaces needed by any extension points they define. Other plug-ins export a lot of classes because they work more like a traditional JAR.

Comment: If the plugin defines an extension point and also specifies class attribute in it's schema to be based on some other class, but this other class does not exist, then what happens?

Comment: For example, I have this in schema file (.exsd) of a plugin, <meta.attribute kind="java" basedOn="org.eclipse.parentplugin.parentPluginClass"/>. However, there is no such class/java file at org.eclipse.parentplugin. What happens in this case? Is this an invalid extension-point?

Comment: No, the basedOn value must be a class or interface that exists somewhere (does not have to be in your plugin).

Comment: What if that is really not the case? Actually, I am working on a plugin extension. And the plugin I am trying to extend offers an extension-point based on a class which is not present in the path specified in it's schema. Do I take this up with the guys who look after this plugin? Also, if extension-point is not available, is it possible to write plugin extension for the original plugin only based on the classes/interfaces exported in the Export-Package list by the original plugin?

Comment: As long as the class is exported by a plugin it should be OK.

Comment: If extension point is not provided then what will trigger the loading and execution of the plugin extension written only using classes exported in the export package list by the original plugin as no extension point means no extension element for adding into plugin.xml? Does this case need any special handling?

Comment: You have to give Eclipse some reason to look at your plugin, like defining a menu action that your plugin provides.